# HTML website resizing issue

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of building a website for a customer. MY problem is with one page. Whenever the page goes to a different sized viewing window the entire page breaks. I have already set a viewpoint, and even tried switching all of my pixel values, to show percents of the page. None of this however has fixed my problem. Below is my code for the broken web page. I have tried using the div tag to try and create spacing, yet it never works, no matter what I try I can't get it to view properly on other viewing platforms. This includes mobile and when the browser is not in full screen.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
<title>About Us</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainjs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maincss.css">  
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tb.jpg">
</head>

<header>
<center>
    <img src="FIMM USA Columbus.jpg" class="logo">
    <p><em><strong>About Us</strong></em></p>
</center>   
</header>

<body>
<hr class="yellowb">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <th><a href="index.html" class="button">Home</a></th>
            <th><a href="products.html" class="button">Products</a></th>
            <th><a href="about.html" class="button">About Us</a></th>
        </table>        
    <hr class="yellowb1">
<div class="round">
    <center><h3>Important Name Here</h3></center>
        <p class="white2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum non nulla non tempor. Praesent quam augue, finibus eu nibh vitae, rutrum pellentesque dui. Nam orci dolor, euismod sit amet arcu in, fringilla aliquet est. Aliquam rhoncus et nibh a lobortis. Phasellus tempus tincidunt turpis, at sollicitudin risus dapibus id. Donec accumsan sem blandit ex faucibus, in aliquam metus molestie. Etiam ac metus risus. Phasellus vitae semper est. Pellentesque sed accumsan neque. Duis mattis euismod ante ac sollicitudin. Duis quis leo nec velit mattis volutpat vel quis dui. Vestibulum pretium felis massa, ac pretium nisi congue iaculis. Nunc at dolor consectetur, molestie odio vitae, tempus odio. Fusce erat nulla, facilisis id sodales nec, mattis et orci. Nam et tortor est.</p>   
</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="gray.jpg"></div> 
<div class="round">
    <center><h3>Important Name Here</h3></center>
        <p class="white2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum non nulla non tempor. Praesent quam augue, finibus eu nibh vitae, rutrum pellentesque dui. Nam orci dolor, euismod sit amet arcu in, fringilla aliquet est. Aliquam rhoncus et nibh a lobortis. Phasellus tempus tincidunt turpis, at sollicitudin risus dapibus id. Donec accumsan sem blandit ex faucibus, in aliquam metus molestie. Etiam ac metus risus. Phasellus vitae semper est. Pellentesque sed accumsan neque. Duis mattis euismod ante ac sollicitudin. Duis quis leo nec velit mattis volutpat vel quis dui. Vestibulum pretium felis massa, ac pretium nisi congue iaculis. Nunc at dolor consectetur, molestie odio vitae, tempus odio. Fusce erat nulla, facilisis id sodales nec, mattis et orci. Nam et tortor est.</p>   
</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="gray.jpg"></div>
<div class="round">
    <center><h3>Important Name Here</h3></center>
        <p class="white2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum non nulla non tempor. Praesent quam augue, finibus eu nibh vitae, rutrum pellentesque dui. Nam orci dolor, euismod sit amet arcu in, fringilla aliquet est. Aliquam rhoncus et nibh a lobortis. Phasellus tempus tincidunt turpis, at sollicitudin risus dapibus id. Donec accumsan sem blandit ex faucibus, in aliquam metus molestie. Etiam ac metus risus. Phasellus vitae semper est. Pellentesque sed accumsan neque. Duis mattis euismod ante ac sollicitudin. Duis quis leo nec velit mattis volutpat vel quis dui. Vestibulum pretium felis massa, ac pretium nisi congue iaculis. Nunc at dolor consectetur, molestie odio vitae, tempus odio. Fusce erat nulla, facilisis id sodales nec, mattis et orci. Nam et tortor est.</p>   
</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="gray.jpg"></div>     
</body> 

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    color: yellow;
    font-family: arial;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%;
}
.logo {
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
}
.yellowb {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.yellowb1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
button {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 70px;
}
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
.buildt {
    height: 15%;
    width: 50%;
}
.rightdiv {
    float: right;
    width: 65%;
    height: 40%;
    text-decoration: outline 3px solid yellow;

}
.largery {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.white {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-indent: 50px;
}
.product {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}
.rline {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 8px solid yellow;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 34%;
    height: 40%;
    float: left;
}
.ltext {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40.5%;
}
.white1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-indent: 45px;
}
.white2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-indent: 45px;
}
.scale {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.div1 {
        border: 5px solid yellow;
        padding: 15px;
}
.left {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 20%;
}
.right {
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 20%;
}
.middle {
    width: 55%;
}
.round {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    width: 75%;
    height: 15%; 
    float: right;
}
.round1 {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%; 
}
.oh {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: don't judge him, instead point him to a direction, to help him improve your skills.

Comment: It might help if you show your desired layout and what exactly is going wrong. I don't see an obvious problem with [the layout](https://jsfiddle.net/gmyq028o/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to rely on viewports alone to render a page. You should be adding media queries to your code. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Also, when putting that code in jsfiddle.net, nothing is "breaking" per see. It just looks like it's not mobile responsive.

Comment: What is happening on my side is that the layout of the site "breaks" and it puts different divs into different locations

Comment: you need help to understand responsive design, your layout is not changing in a different screen size, you need think on it since the first css code. making it fluid, then, inserting a breakpoint when your layout "breaks" at certain point

Comment: here are my friend @Al-x https://www.udemy.com/design-and-develop-a-killer-website-with-html5-and-css3/